# Brokered message transfer between iOS device and backend using Azure Bus service queue

Tags: ios, sockets, azure, azureservicebus, brokeredmessage

I am trying send data between iOS device and backend using azure bus service .
But all the things that I found on Microsoft azure portal provide Accounts storage methods to azure or through hub providing push notifications.

I am trying to send a "Brokered message"(used for distributed systems) through a queue client using bus service Queue(FIFO). I also came across this method but found that on .net C# not for iOS even Our team here is able to send the data in .net but no luck with Mobile systems(iOS and Android)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh780762.aspx) for Azure Service Bus from iOS or Android. There's also a good walk-through [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-brokered-tutorial-rest/) you can try.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but what i can see in this tutorial , is for .net not for Java or objectvive c/Swift  , native langauges for Mobile.